# Impersonating Law Enforcement

Tags: penetration-test, social-engineering

Obviously impersonating a law enforcement officer on an engagement is illegal but badguys don't care about the law. If a company wanted to allow impersonating LE and have it in clear writing in the contract does that make it so the tester won't go to prison? Has anyone ever been on an engagement or know of one where this happened?

Comment: This is why they often carry "get out of jail free" cards

Comment: Let's that a look at the general case: "Obviously [this crime] is a crime with a potential prison sentence.  If a company made a contract with me to commit [this crime] on their behalf, does that make [this crime] not a crime with a potential prison sentence?"  Substitute your favorite crimes and see what you think.

Comment: @Anti-weakpasswords Most social engineering tests involve illegal entry/breaking and entering. If the breaking and entering is performed with written permission it's not a crime. As detailed in my answer it depends on *what* you are actually doing exactly. If impersonating a police officer  is illegal then you need to clear it with the police first (this is what most gameshows do as well when performing pranks).

Comment: @LucasKauffman A company can give permission to enter their company grounds and even damage their property while doing so. But impersonating an officer is not a crime against the company. It is a crime against the private person you talk to and the state whose authority you undermine through this act. A company can not give you permission to commit crimes against someone else.

Comment: @Philip Exactly, that's why I stated that you *need consent* from the **local police office**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to any social engineering engagement make sure your contract is air tight. Also, when impersonating a police officer make sure you are allowed to do so and that it is not forbidden by law.  Even when having a free out of jail card it could still be that it is illegal. The law still supersedes whatever you put in a contract. I'd suggest contacting your local police office first **through** your lawyer and have consent in writing from the police responsible.

If you haven't contacted your lawyer yet, please do so, while we can share experiences every country and region has it's own local laws which can differ significantly. The only way to ensure the safety of your testers is to go through a lawyer.

Comment: Do you have a reference to a government site recognizing "free out of jail" or "get out of jail free" cards?

Comment: Where do you see me referencing free out of jail cards?

Comment: @Anti-weakpasswords Depending on where you live, you might be able to acquire such a card through your local crime syndicate :)

Comment: @Lucas Kauffman  - I was referring the reference in your third sentence "Even when having a free out of jail card"

Comment: And I clearly state that it still could be a illegal... A free out of jail card is no more than a signed contract between two parties that in the event that you caught breaking and entering that you weren't actually doing that illegaly?